# How to find out which cell was right clicked (despite a differing selection)

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, nsmenu

I am using an `NSTableView` which is connected to a `NSMenu` in IB.

Now I can right click a selected cell and choose the context menu for the selected item.

This is all fine, however, the TableView can show context menu for items which are not selected:

[image]

So now the action applies to the selected item in the list, rather than item that was actually right-clicked: I want to open `6` but eventually `1` is opened in the browser.

This is how I handle the click Event:

```
- (IBAction)openInBrowserClicked:(id)sender {

    Issue *i = self.issuesController.selectedObjects.lastObject;
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:i.URL];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the table views `clickedRow` property/method to determine on which row the click was placed. Next get from your data source the object for the clicked row and that is it.

Comment: Works beautifully. This is how I get the object from my Array controller: `[self.issuesController.arrangedObjects objectAtIndex:self.myTableView.clickedRow];
`